# RX6600 - Bluescreen & Blackscreen while gaming | Even after Clean-Install?

Tags: windows-11, gpu

I recently ordered a new GPU, the RX6600.

After the installation everything went smoothly. PC booted, drivers installed with the official Radeon software, PC restarted...

When I wanted to start a game, I got a bluescreen after entering the fictitious world (unfortunately much too short to read the error message).

After several attempts it stayed the same; bluescreen here, bluescreen there. And that in almost all games I had installed on my PC.

I now performed a clean install of Windows, could have been a problem with my Windows installation.

In the first moment it was exactly that. The problem was solved...
...or so I thought.

When I downloaded some games and tried to join one of the games again, again the same thing: BLUESCREEN.
After the first bluescreen, there where only immediatley black screens, so no bluescreens anymore. But still: I cant play any game without my pc being crashed.

I should also mention that I ordered the same graphics card a few months ago, and it triggered bluescreens just like the current one.
I sold it to my friend, installed it at his place, and everything ran without problems.
The strange thing?
Well... It has exactly the same specs as my PC. (Except for the case)
In addition, the same Windows, namely Windows 11.

Another friend, to whom I ordered and installed the exact same GPU, also had no problems, and he had different specs.

My specifications:

Mainboard: MSI B450-A Pro MAX So.AM4 Dual Channel DDR4 ATX Retail

- CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 5500 6x 3.60GHz So.AM4 BOX
- RAM: 16GB (2x 8GB) Corsair Vengeance RGB PRO SL black DDR4-3200
- SSD: 1TB Intenso SSD M.2 2 2280 - PCIe 3.0 x4 NVMe
- (previous) graphics card: GTX 1050 ti (with this everything ran without problems)
- Power supply: 550 Watt

Can you make any sense of this?

---

EDIT:
All the bluescreens are unfortunately just a perceived 2 ms on the screen.

The bluescreen only came the first 2-3 times. After that, only immediately blackscreen, so no more bluescreen.

Now I just filmed with my phone while starting a game.

A bluescreen came up again, and I have the error message on picture.

It reads: "CRITICAL PROCESS DIED".

Comment: They have the same exact PSU? What brand and model is the PSU? I assume you can run the dmp files through WinDBG and post the analysis for us?

Comment: @Ramhound No, not the same PSU, but the mostly same Power/Watts.

I have a HKC V-Power 550W

And he has a Sharkoon SHP Bronze 500 Watt

And - by the way - unfortunaly I don't know what you by your last sentence.

Comment: WinDBG is a tool that can create and analysis the cause of a BSOD by reading the .dmp file that is created when Windows crashes.

Comment: Are you using the latest drivers? Windows has an issue with installing those at the same time as running windows updates (which I guess is a thing for a new install).

Answer (score 0):

The solution was a defective power supply.

I installed a new one and everything works fine now.